# how to encrypt/decrypt the video url

Tags: iphone

I have video URLs in my app. I want to encrypt/decrypt those URLs. I'm trying so much but I could not find any way to do this.

Please . Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [ROT13](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13)

As you want to both encrypt and decrypt the URLs in the app, the key to do so is also in the app.

Therefore the key is available to an 'attacker'.

Therefore, we are talking about obfuscation and nothing more.

Whatever happens, when you actually *fetch* the video in your app, doing so can be observed by an attacker.

So ROT13 is probably the right trade-off of security to convenience for you.

Comment: I was writing up a similar answer, taking the cryptography part more seriously, but you nailed it with the trade off.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than encrypt the URL's as Will suggested, it might be more useful to replace them with identifiers. These can be a hash (eg sha, md..) of something unique, potentially unique to each user. The hashes can be stored in the db, and when the user tries to fetch the video, you can authenticate the action against the user permissions.

Comment: Absolutely a better overall solution to use the server side to *authenticate* the user rather than trying to obfuscate URLs